# Whys is Graphics.Clear(); Not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.drawing

I am doing some revision for my comp103 paper and I cant get the button with the Graphics.Clear(); method to clear the graphics paper. Can someone please point out the error in my code as I have spent about an hour trying to find an answer on the net.

Sorry for asking such a noob question.

Here is the code:

```
namespace Week_4_Ex1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int height1 = 150; // A constant that stores the flags height
        const int width1 = 100; // A constant that stores the flags width

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Button event that Draws a flag
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics Paper = this.CreateGraphics(); // Creates graphics paper to draw on
            Brush br1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue); // Creates a blue brush to draw with
            Brush br2 = new SolidBrush (Color.Orange); // Creates a orange brush to draw with
            Brush br3 = new SolidBrush (Color.Red); // Creates a red brush to draw with

            Pen Pen1 = new Pen(Color.Blue);         // Creates a blue pen to draw with
            Pen Pen2 = new Pen(Color.Orange);       // Creates a orange pen to draw with
            Pen Pen3 = new Pen(Color.Red);          // Creates a red pen to draw with

            //The following code draws a flag
            Paper.DrawRectangle(Pen1, 10, 10, width1, height1); // Draws a blue rectangle
            Paper.FillRectangle(br1, 10, 10, width1, height1); // Fills the rectangle with blue
            Paper.DrawRectangle(Pen2, 110, 10, width1, height1); // Draws a blue rectangle
            Paper.FillRectangle(br2, 110, 10, width1, height1); // Fills the rectangle with blue
            Paper.DrawRectangle(Pen3, 210, 10, width1, height1); // Draws a blue rectangle
            Paper.FillRectangle(br3, 210, 10, width1, height1); // Fills the rectangle with blue

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Button that closes the form
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close(); // Closes the form
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears the picturebox
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void btnErase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics.Clear(); //**THIS DOESN'T WORK**
        }

    }
}
```

Cheers,
Rab

Comment: First off, a quick view of MSDN reveals that `Clear` is not a static method of type `Graphics` and that it further requires a `color` parameter.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Your class doesn't have a Graphics member, and the `Graphics.Clear` method is not static...

Comment: If I remove the Graphics.Clear(); it will run in "Start debugging" and do everything as intended. However I am having problem with creating a button that clears the form. So by "doesnt work" I mean I cant get the Graphics.Clear(); to work.

Comment: Cheers for the help guys. I think I see where I am falling short :)

Comment: You should not be drawing onto the form in this manner.  Try this experiment:  After clicking your button, drag another window (such as notepad) across the form.  What happens?  All drawing on the form should take place in the OnPaint method.  See this article for more information:  http://bobpowell.net/creategraphics.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try [Graphics.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear.aspx) Method with color as below.

```
this.CreateGraphics().Clear(Form1.ActiveForm.BackColor);
```

Comment: @Damith, Graphics objects are unmanaged objects. If we clear it like this, will it cause memory leak ?